# Parse View's property which is set

Tags: android, json

I want to make an function which return JsonObject of attributes or property which is set in View

Suppose I have LinearLayout which contain one TextView and one Button

```
LinearLayout
width = (match_parent)
height = (match_parent)
orientation = "vertical"

                 ----- Button
                width = (wrap_parent)
                height = (wrap_parent)
                text = "Button"
               ----- TextView
                width = (wrap_parent)
                height = (wrap_parent)
                text = "TextView"
```

I want to make function, in that I will pass object of LinearLayout and it will return me JsonObject with all attributes

```
{
    "LinearLayout": {
        "android:width": "match_parent",
        "android:height": "match_parent",
        "android:orientation": "vertical",
        "child_view": {
            "Button": {
                "android:width": "wrap_content",
                "android:height": "wrap_content",
                "android:text": "Button"
            },
            "TextView": {
                "android:width": "wrap_content",
                "android:height": "wrap_content",
                "android:text": "TextView"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible, because I want to store view, so I thought that it is the only way if I create it's JSON and store it in preference, after if I want to use I will retrieve JSON and create dynamic view

Comment: Nice question dude ;)

Comment: Thanks alot Kaushal, have you any idea?

Comment: I don't think we can fetch properties of a view programmatically; like say if we fetch width attr of a view, it woulds return int value in px rather than wrap_content or match_parent property

Comment: @DhavalPatel it will be ok for me if it is possible

Comment: We can get all properties of the respected component and then build JSON instead of getting only declared ones. The result should be same. The only difference is that while building JSON, it will consider all the properties and by doing the reverse(converting in XML), it will set all the properties in XML. For example, if XML component set "GRAVITY", programmatically you get the integer value of it from LayoutParams and set it in your JSON.

Comment: But for that I have to write all property for all view right Like ImageView I have to use it's getImageResource like property which TextView has not

Comment: why do you want to save the view like this ?

Comment: Because I want to display that UI, in other screens, which UI user has used.

Comment: By creating JSONObject, I can store it into preference and I can retrieve it from Preference and make dynamic view where need